# C99 - Lexer for the Monkey Programming Language from the book "Writing An Interpreter In Go"

Tags: c, api, compiler, lexical-analysis, monkey

Below is a C version of a lexer for [the Monkey programming language](https://monkeylang.org/), originally written in Go, as presented in the book [Writing An Interpreter In Go](https://interpreterbook.com/).

LOC: 371. (Excluding the tests.)

### Language:

Copy pasting from the book:

> Here is how we bind values to names in Monkey:

```
let age = 1;
let name = "Monkey"; 
let result = 10 * (20 / 2);
```

> Besides integers, booleans and strings, the Monkey interpreter we’re going to build will also support arrays and hashes. Here’s what binding an array of integers to a name looks like:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

> And here is a hash, where values are associated with keys:

```
let thorsten = {"name": "Thorsten", "age": 28};
```

> Accessing the elements in arrays and hashes is done with index expressions:

```
myArray[0] // => 1 
thorsten["name"] // => "Thorsten"
```

> The let statements can also be used to bind functions to names. Here’s a small function that adds two numbers:

```
let add = fn(a, b) { return a + b; };
```

> But Monkey not only supports return statements. Implicit return values are also possible, which means we can leave out the return if we want to:

```
let add = fn(a, b) { a + b; };
```

> And calling a function is as easy as you’d expect:

```
add(1, 2);
```

> A more complex function, such as a fibonacci function that returns the Nth Fibonacci number, might look like this:

```
let fibonacci = fn(x) { 
    if (x == 0) { 
        0
    } else { 
        if (x == 1) {
             1 
        } else { 
             fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
        }
    }
};
```

> Note the recursive calls to fibonacci itself! Monkey also supports a special type of functions, called higher order functions. These are functions that take other functions as arguments. Here is an example:

```
let twice = fn(f, x) { return f(f(x)); }; 
let addTwo = fn(x) { return x + 2; }; 
twice(addTwo, 2); // => 6
```

### Directory Structure:

```
.
├── lexer
│   ├── lexer.c
│   └── lexer.h
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── repl
│   └── repl.c
├── struct.txt
├── tests
│   ├── bin
│   └── lexer_test.c
├── token
│   ├── token.c
│   └── token.h
└── util
    ├── util.c
    └── util.h

6 directories, 11 files
```

### Code:

lexer.h:

```c
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H 1

#include "../token/token.h"

typedef struct lexer {
    const char *input;
    size_t      input_len;
    size_t      pos;        /* Current position in input (points to current char). */
    size_t      read_pos;   /* Current reading position in input (after current char). */
    char        ch;         /* Current char under examination. */
} Lexer;

Lexer lexer_new(const char input[static 1]);
Token lexer_next(Lexer l[static 1]);

#endif /* LEXER_H */
```

lexer.c:

```c
// TODO: Change the API to hide the lexer's internals.

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "lexer.h"
#include "../token/token.h"
#include "../util/util.h"

static void read_char(Lexer l[static 1])
{
    l->ch = l->read_pos >= l->input_len ? '\0' : l->input[l->read_pos];
    l->pos = l->read_pos;
    ++l->read_pos;
}

static char peek_char(Lexer l)
{
    return l.read_pos >= l.input_len ? '\0' : l.input[l.read_pos];
}

static int is_letter(char ch)
{
    return ch == '_' || isalpha((unsigned char)ch) != 0;
}

static const char *read_ident(Lexer l[static 1], size_t len[static 1])
{
    const size_t orig_pos = l->pos;
    for (; is_letter(l->ch) != 0; read_char(l)) ;
    *len = l->pos - orig_pos;
    return l->input + orig_pos;
}

static const char *read_int(Lexer l[static 1], size_t len[static 1])
{
    const size_t orig_pos = l->pos;
    for (; isdigit((unsigned char)l->ch) != 0; read_char(l)) ;
    *len = l->pos - orig_pos;
    return l->input + orig_pos;
}

static const char *read_string(Lexer l[static 1], size_t len[static 1])
{
    /* Monkey doesn't support escape characters. 
     * TODO: Perhaps return NULL on EOF. 
     */
    const size_t orig_pos = l->pos + 1;

    do {
        read_char(l);
    } while (l->ch != '"' && l->ch != '\0');

    *len = l->pos - orig_pos;
    return l->input + orig_pos;
}

static void skip_whitespace(Lexer l[static 1])
{
    for (; isspace((unsigned char)l->ch) != 0; read_char(l)) ;
}

Lexer lexer_new(const char input[static 1])
{
    Lexer l = {
        .input = input,
        .input_len = strlen(input),
    };
    read_char(&l);
    return l;
}

Token lexer_next(Lexer l[static 1])
{
    Token t;
    skip_whitespace(l);

    switch (l->ch) {
        case '=':
            if (peek_char(*l) == '=') {
                read_char(l);
                t = token_new(TOK_EQ, "==");
            } else {
                t = token_new(TOK_ASSIGN, "=");
            }
            break;

        case '+':
            t = token_new(TOK_PLUS, "+");
            break;

        case '-':
            t = token_new(TOK_MINUS, "-");
            break;

        case '*':
            t = token_new(TOK_ASTERISK, "*");
            break;

        case '/':
            t = token_new(TOK_SLASH, "/");
            break;

        case '!':
            if (peek_char(*l) == '=') {
                read_char(l);
                t = token_new(TOK_NOT_EQ, "!=");
            } else {
                t = token_new(TOK_BANG, "!");
            }
            break;

        case '<':
            t = token_new(TOK_LT, "<");
            break;

        case '>':
            t = token_new(TOK_GT, ">");
            break;

        case ',':
            t = token_new(TOK_COMMA, ",");
            break;

        case ';':
            t = token_new(TOK_SEMICOLON, ";");
            break;

        case ':':
            t = token_new(TOK_COLON, ":");
            break;

        case '(':
            t = token_new(TOK_LPAREN, "(");
            break;

        case ')':
            t = token_new(TOK_RPAREN, ")");
            break;

        case '{':
            t = token_new(TOK_LBRACE, "{");
            break;

        case '}':
            t = token_new(TOK_RBRACE, "}");
            break;

        case '[':
            t = token_new(TOK_LBRACKET, "[");
            break;

        case ']':
            t = token_new(TOK_RBRACKET, "]");
            break;

        case '\0':
            t = token_new(TOK_EOF, "");
            break;

        case '"': {
            size_t len = 0;
            t.lit = read_string(l, &len);
            t.type = TOK_STRING;
            t.lit = util_memstr(len, t.lit);
        } break;

        default:
            if (is_letter(l->ch) != 0) {
                size_t len = 0;
                t.lit = read_ident(l, &len);
                t.type = token_lookup_ident(len, t.lit);
                t.lit = util_memstr(len, t.lit);
                return t;
            } else if (isdigit((unsigned char)l->ch) != 0) {
                size_t len = 0;
                t.type = TOK_INT;
                t.lit = read_int(l, &len);
                t.lit = util_memstr(len, t.lit);
                return t;
            } 
            t = token_new(TOK_ILLEGAL, util_memstr(1, &l->ch));
    }

    read_char(l);
    return t;
}
```

token.h:

```c
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H 1

#include <stddef.h>

#define FOREACH_TOK(_) \
    _(TOK_ILLEGAL)      \
    _(TOK_EOF)          \
    _(TOK_IDENT)        \
    _(TOK_INT)          \
    _(TOK_STRING)       \
    _(TOK_ASSIGN)       \
    _(TOK_PLUS)         \
    _(TOK_MINUS)        \
    _(TOK_BANG)         \
    _(TOK_ASTERISK)     \
    _(TOK_SLASH)        \
    _(TOK_LT)           \
    _(TOK_GT)           \
    _(TOK_EQ)           \
    _(TOK_NOT_EQ)       \
    _(TOK_COMMA)        \
    _(TOK_SEMICOLON)    \
    _(TOK_COLON)        \
    _(TOK_LPAREN)       \
    _(TOK_RPAREN)       \
    _(TOK_LBRACE)       \
    _(TOK_RBRACE)       \
    _(TOK_RBRACKET)     \
    _(TOK_LBRACKET)     \
    _(TOK_FUNCTION)     \
    _(TOK_LET)          \
    _(TOK_TRUE)         \
    _(TOK_FALSE)        \
    _(TOK_IF)           \
    _(TOK_ELSE)         \
    _(TOK_RETURN)       \

#define GEN_ENUM(ENUM) ENUM,

typedef enum {
    FOREACH_TOK(GEN_ENUM)
} TokenType;

typedef struct Token {
    TokenType   type;
    const char *lit;
} Token;

TokenType token_lookup_ident(size_t len, const char ident[static len]);
Token token_new(TokenType type, const char lit[static 1]);
void token_delete(Token t);
const char *token_to_str(TokenType t);

#endif /* TOKEN_H */
```

token.c:

```c
#include "token.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GEN_STR(STR) #STR,

static const char *const tok_strs[] = {
    FOREACH_TOK(GEN_STR)
};

static const size_t tok_strs_count = sizeof tok_strs / sizeof *tok_strs;

const char *token_to_str(TokenType t)
{
    return t < 0 || t > tok_strs_count ? NULL : tok_strs[t];
}

TokenType token_lookup_ident(size_t len, const char ident[static len])
{
    static struct keyword {
        const char *const kw;
        TokenType kw_type;
    } const kws[] = {
        { "fn",     TOK_FUNCTION },
        { "let",    TOK_LET      },
        { "true",   TOK_TRUE     },
        { "false",  TOK_FALSE    },
        { "if",     TOK_IF       },
        { "else",   TOK_ELSE     },
        { "return", TOK_RETURN   },
    };

    static const size_t kws_count = sizeof kws / sizeof kws[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < kws_count; ++i) {
        if (strncmp(ident, kws[i].kw, len) == 0) {
            return kws[i].kw_type;
        }
    }

    return TOK_IDENT;
}

Token token_new(TokenType type, const char lit[static 1])
{
    return (Token) {
        .type = type,
        .lit = lit,
    };
}

static bool is_kw(TokenType t)
{
    static const TokenType kws[] = {
        TOK_FUNCTION,
        TOK_LET,
        TOK_TRUE,
        TOK_FALSE,
        TOK_IF,
        TOK_ELSE,
        TOK_RETURN,
    };

    return memchr(kws, t, sizeof kws) != NULL;
}

static bool is_dynamic_alloc(TokenType t)
{
    return (t == TOK_INT   
            || t == TOK_ILLEGAL 
            || t == TOK_IDENT
            || t == TOK_STRING
            || is_kw(t));
}

void token_delete(Token t)
{
    if (is_dynamic_alloc(t.type)) {
        free((char *)t.lit);
    }
}
```

util.h:

```c
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H 1

#include "stdio.h"

char *util_memstr(size_t n, const char s[static n]);
char *util_readline(FILE stream[static 1], size_t len[static 1]);

#endif /* UTIL_H */
```

util.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *util_memstr(size_t n, const char s[static n])
{
    char *const p = malloc(n + 1);

    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, n);
        p[n] = '\0';
    }

    return p;
}

char *util_readline(FILE stream[static 1], size_t len[static 1])
{
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    char *line = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        if (count >= capacity) {
            capacity = capacity < BUFSIZ ? BUFSIZ : capacity * 2;
            char *const tmp = realloc(line, capacity + 1);

            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(line);
                return NULL;
            }

            line = tmp;
        }

        const int c = getc(stream);

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
            if (c == EOF) {
                if (feof(stream)) {
                    if (!count) {
                        free(line);
                        return NULL;
                    }
                    /* Return what was read. */
                    break;
                }
                /* Read error. */
                free(line);
                return NULL;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            line[count] = (char) c;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    
    *len = count;
    return line;
}
```

#### REPL:

repl.c:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../lexer/lexer.h"
#include "../token/token.h"
#include "../util/util.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello! This is the Monkey Programming Language!\n"
            "Type in commands:\n");

    while (true) {
        fputs(">> ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);

        size_t len = 0;
        char *const line = util_readline(stdin, &len);

        if (line == NULL) {
            if (feof(stdin)) {
                break;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: an unexpected error occured.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        len[line] = '\0';
        Lexer l = lexer_new(line);

        for (Token t = lexer_next(&l); t.type != TOK_EOF; token_delete(t), t = lexer_next(&l)) {
            printf("{Type: %s, Literal: %s}\n", token_to_str(t.type), t.lit);
        }
        free(line);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Tests:

And tests for the lexer; lexer_test.c:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "../lexer/lexer.h"
#include "../token/token.h"

#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
    #include <stdnoreturn.h>
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define noreturn        __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
    #define noreturn        /**/
#endif 

typedef struct {
    const TokenType   expected_type;
    const char *const expected_lit;
} test;

static size_t tests_run = 0;

static noreturn void fatal(const char fmt[static 1], ...) 
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    putchar('\n');
    va_end(ap);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void run_test(const char input[static 1], 
                     const test tests[static 1])
{
    ++tests_run;
    fprintf(stderr, "[INFO]: Running test suite %zu...\n", tests_run);
    Lexer l = lexer_new(input);

    for (const test *p_tests = tests; p_tests->expected_lit != NULL; ++p_tests) {
        const Token t = lexer_next(&l);

        if (t.lit == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[FAIL]: error: failed to allocate memory for token.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        const test tt = *p_tests;

        if (t.type != tt.expected_type) {
            fatal("[FAIL]: tests[%zu] - Tokentype wrong. Expected '%s', Got '%s'.\n",
                 p_tests - tests, token_to_str(tt.expected_type), token_to_str(t.type));
        }

        if (strcmp(t.lit, tt.expected_lit) != 0) {
            fatal("[FAIL]: tests[%zu] - Literal wrong. Expected '%s', Got '%s'.\n",
                 p_tests - tests, tt.expected_lit, t.lit);
        }

        token_delete(t);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "[INFO]: All tests passed!\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    run_test("=+(){},;#", (const test[]) {
        { TOK_ASSIGN,    "=" },
        { TOK_PLUS,      "+" },
        { TOK_LPAREN,    "(" },
        { TOK_RPAREN,    ")" },
        { TOK_LBRACE,    "{" },
        { TOK_RBRACE,    "}" },
        { TOK_COMMA,     "," },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON, ";" },
        { TOK_ILLEGAL,   "#" },
        { TOK_EOF,       ""  },
        { -1,            NULL},
    });

    run_test("let five = 5;"
            "let ten = 10;"
            "let add = fn(x, y) { x + y; };"
            "let result = add(five, ten);",
            (const test[]) {
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "five"  },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "ten"   },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "add"   },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_FUNCTION,     "fn"    },
        { TOK_LPAREN,       "("     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "x"     },
        { TOK_COMMA,        ","     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "y"     },
        { TOK_RPAREN,       ")"     },
        { TOK_LBRACE,       "{"     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "x"     },
        { TOK_PLUS,         "+"     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "y"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_RBRACE,       "}"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "result"},
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "add"   },
        { TOK_LPAREN,       "("     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "five"  },
        { TOK_COMMA,        ","     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "ten"   },
        { TOK_RPAREN,       ")"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_EOF,          ""      },
        { -1,               NULL    },
    });

    run_test("let five = 5;"
            "let ten = 10;"
            "let add = fn(x, y) {"
            "x + y;"
            "};"
            "let result = add(five, ten);"
            "!-/*5;"
            "5 < 10 > 5;"
            "if (5 < 10) {"
            "return true;"
            "} else {"
            "return false;"
            "}"
            "10 == 10;"
            "10 != 9;",
            (const test[]) {
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "five"  },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "ten"   },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "add"   },
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_FUNCTION,     "fn"    },
        { TOK_LPAREN,       "("     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "x"     },
        { TOK_COMMA,        ","     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "y"     },
        { TOK_RPAREN,       ")"     },
        { TOK_LBRACE,       "{"     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "x"     },
        { TOK_PLUS,         "+"     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "y"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_RBRACE,       "}"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_LET,          "let"   },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "result"},
        { TOK_ASSIGN,       "="     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "add"   },
        { TOK_LPAREN,       "("     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "five"  },
        { TOK_COMMA,        ","     },
        { TOK_IDENT,        "ten"   },
        { TOK_RPAREN,       ")"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_BANG,         "!"     },
        { TOK_MINUS,        "-"     },
        { TOK_SLASH,        "/"     },
        { TOK_ASTERISK,     "*"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_LT,           "<"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_GT,           ">"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_IF,           "if"    },
        { TOK_LPAREN,       "("     },
        { TOK_INT,          "5"     },
        { TOK_LT,           "<"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_RPAREN,       ")"     },
        { TOK_LBRACE,       "{"     },
        { TOK_RETURN,       "return"},
        { TOK_TRUE,         "true"  },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_RBRACE,       "}"     },
        { TOK_ELSE,         "else"  },
        { TOK_LBRACE,       "{"     },
        { TOK_RETURN,       "return"},
        { TOK_FALSE,        "false" },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_RBRACE,       "}"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_EQ,           "=="    },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_INT,          "10"    },
        { TOK_NOT_EQ,       "!="    },
        { TOK_INT,          "9"     },
        { TOK_SEMICOLON,    ";"     },
        { TOK_EOF,          ""      },
        { -1,               NULL    },
    });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Makefile:

```
CC  := gcc-13

CFLAGS  += -std=c99
CFLAGS  += -DNDEBUG
CFLAGS  += -g3
CFLAGS  += -ggdb
CFLAGS  += -fPIC
CFLAGS  += -gdwarf-4
CFLAGS  += -Wall
CFLAGS  += -Wextra
CFLAGS  += -Wwrite-strings
CFLAGS  += -Wno-parentheses
CFLAGS  += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS  += -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS  += -Wconversion
CFLAGS  += -Wno-unused-function
CFLAGS  += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS  += -fanalyzer

BINDIR      := bin
TEST_BINDIR := tests/bin

SRCDIRS     := lexer repl token util
SRCS        := $(filter-out repl/repl.c, $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c, $(SRCDIRS))))

TESTDIR     := tests
TEST_SRCS   := $(wildcard $(TESTDIR)/*.c)

TARGET      := $(BINDIR)/repl
TEST_TARGET := $(TEST_BINDIR)/lexer_test

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): repl/repl.c $(SRCS) | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(TEST_TARGET): $(SRCS) $(TEST_SRCS) | $(TEST_BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

test: $(TEST_TARGET)
    @echo "Running tests..."
    @./$<   

$(BINDIR) $(TEST_BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

rclean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)

tclean:
    rm -rf $(TEST_BINDIR)

fclean_repl:
    rm $(TARGET) 

fclean_test:
    rm $(TEST_TARGET)

.PHONY: all test clean fclean_repl fclean_test

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

### Review Request:

- project structure
- filenaming/code splitting
- naming and design
- makefile
- general coding comments

In trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation, I have defined the structure for the lexer in the header file. Do you see a way around that?

Is there some standard function I can use instead of `util_memstr()`?

It'd also be nice if I could cut down on LOC.

For ease, here's the github repository: [lexer-c](https://github.com/Melkor-1/lexer-c).

Run `make` to build the REPL (it'll be in the `bin` directory), and `make test` to build and run the tests.

For the curious, here's the Go version: [lexer-go](https://github.com/Melkor-1/lexer-go).

Comment: Next one would likely be a C++ version.

Comment: Too many unknowns. Does Monkey have comments? string literals? escape characters? Does it allow identifiers like `xyz123`? Underscores in identifieres? I'd rather see a formal definition of the language.